# Word style "keep with next" except on last item

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm writing specifications using Word documents with a general style like this:

```
# Heading 1
intro paragraph
* bullet1
* bullet2
* bullet3

# Heading 2
intro paragraph
* bullet1
* bullet2

# Heading 3
intro paragraph
* bullet1
* bullet2
* bullet3
* bullet4
* bullet5
```

I want each heading, intro paragraph, and associated bullets to stay together whenever possible. As such, I have styles for each with the Paragraph option "Keep with Next" checked. However, this results in everything sticking together too tightly.

To **fix it** I currently go to the last bullet in each list and change its style to one that does not have "Keep with Next" checked. For example, the bullets have a style "ReqBullet" and I create another style "LastReqBullet" that inherits from "ReqBullet", but which has "Keep with Next" turned off.

*(I could alternatively override the setting on each bullet, but doing it via a style makes it easier to apply, and also easier to see where it is set.)*

Using manual style application is slightly cumbersome, and error-prone. If I add a new item to the end, I have to swap styles. Often I will forget to apply the style until I realize that the formatting is wonky.

#### The question

Is there a way hidden in the bowels of the Style settings to say either:

- Keep this paragraph with the next *but only if it's the same style*, or
- I don't care what the previous paragraph told you, do NOT keep me with it (which I could apply to  the headings)

Comment: I've always done the same as you describe - never discovered a way to improve on that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such setting like this. But, I think you could create a style with Keep With Next turned off just for the blank space after the last bullet. So you need not to change the bullet style when adding new bullet.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the ribbon by adding a button for "Para Keep With Next" and use that button to toggle keep with next for a paragraph.

[image]

An indirect solution but, to me, it makes the lack of this feature less important.
You need a custom group as well because you cannot add items to the standard groups