# Separate Keep With Next Groups

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Is there a way to separate two adjacent Keep With Next groups?

For example, I have six paragraphs. I want a set of three to be their own Keep With with Next block. However, since all six are together, it's treated as one block.

Comment: similar to https://superuser.com/questions/876770/word-style-keep-with-next-except-on-last-item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Keep with Next for the first and second paragraph (this will keep paragraphs 1-3 together), and then set Keep with Next for the fourth and fifth paragraph (this will group paragraphs 4-6).

Comment: That's interesting. I never noticed that that before. Is the following paragraph always included then?

Comment: Yes. The logic of this option is: keep this paragraph together with next paragraph, so when it is applied to a paragraph it means that two paragraphs are affected (current and next).

Comment: Keep with next! I get it.